# Unable to change file encoding to utf-8 using send_data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file, encoding, utf-8

First of all, allow me to wish you all happy reading this question, happy and productive new year.

Here comes the issue: I am unable to change file charset via Rails 3 send_data
I have some content generated via

```
xml_data = ''
x = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target => xml_data, :indent => 1)
```

which i fill then with all sort of data.

When I attempt to send this file for download using this command

```
send_data xml_data.encode('cp1251'),
          :type => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8; header=present',
          :filename => "data.xml"
```

it downloads just fine, but for some reason, when in Linux I request file encoding using

```
> file -bi data.xml
text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I need charset of this file to be utf-8. How can I automatically set it through Rails send_data?

Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: what it return while you do `x.instruct!` It should return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: you can do `x.instruct! :xml, :encoding=>"UTF-8"`

Comment: If you want utf 8, why are you converting to cp1251?

Comment: Rajarshi Das, I did what  you said and now file-bi returns: "application/xml; charset=iso-8859-1", all that changed is text/plain to application/xml but that really doesn't solve my issue. x.instructt! indeed returns what you said.

Comment: Frederick Cheung. XML is intended for use with a third party system and this is strongly specific to other side system.

Comment: what you get while you did `x.instruct!`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: what is your vim encoding status `/etc/vim/vimrc or ~/.vimrc file:` these files?

Comment: set these by `vi ~/.vimrc` puts these `set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8` and then you test the file by `file -bi data.xml`

Comment: What does Vim have to do with file charset? I added the line you said, no luck, still iso-8859-1

Comment: Send_data doesn't change the encoding - just the headers that are sent. It's your call to encode that is changing the data

Comment: I see. So is there a way to do that via code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that for the third party system the XML is used, all UTF-8 encoding is just fine.

In result i ended up with

```
send_data xml_data.encode('utf-8'),
          :type => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8; header=present',
          :filename => "data.xml"
```